# Convert a string of comma separated values to true/false array

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

I am trying to find a way to get the separated values and convert them to an array with false or true

```
$idValues = '111111,222222,333333';
$lubuvnaIDs = explode(",", $idValues);
$groups = '';

foreach($lubuvnaIDs as $row ){
        $groups .= $row .'=>'. true;
}

$newGroups = array($groups);


$dataSub = array (
        'interests' => $newGroups,
);
```

The final output of $newGroups should look like this:

```
$newGroups = array( 
        '111111'    => true,
        '222222'    => true,
        '333333'    => true
);
```

Comment: Do you want `'true'` (a string) or `true` the value `1`

Comment: it needs to be like following  `Array
(
    '111111' => true
    '222222' => true
    '333333' => true
)`

Comment: The only way to do that is to put a text `$newGroups[$row] = 'true';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a loop, you can use `array_fill_keys()` with the list of values from the `explode()`.  Setting the initial value to be true...

```
$newGroups = array_fill_keys(explode(",", $idValues), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just looping through the values and adding them to an array:

```php
$idValues = '111111,222222,333333';
$lubuvnaIDs = explode(",", $idValues);

$newGroups = [];
foreach ($lubuvnaIDs as $id) {
    $newGroups[$id] = true;
}
```

Comment: This way i am getting  `Array
(
    [111111] => 1
    [222222] => 1
    [333333] => 1
)`

Comment: it needs to be  `Array
(
    '111111' => true
    '222222' => true
    '333333' => true
)`

Comment: It depends on what you use to display it. print_r will show it like that because it displays key/value pairs. Use your own final output example and print_r that to see the same as my answer. `[111111] => 1` is essentially the same as `'111111' => true`, depending on what you need it for after this.